# Joining two dataframes on columns they match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. df1 has more elements (3) in column 'Table_name' than df2 (2). I want a resultant dataframe that only outputs the rows where df1 and df2 share the same column names.

df1

```
Table_Name | Type
   id      | int
   name    | string
   position| string
```

df2

```
Table_Name | Type
   id      | float
   name    | string
```

I want this to be the result.

df_result

```
Table_Name | Type
   id      | int
   name    | string
```

This is what i tried but it doesn't work:

```
similar_cols = df1[df1['Table_name'].isin(df2['Table_name'])].dropna()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `loc` here

```
similar_cols = df1.loc[df1['Table_name'].isin(df2['Table_name'])]
```

Comment: Thx for ur answer! I get this error `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match` when i run it

Comment: ah! it is still giving the same original results. Instead of returning a dataframe with the same size and col_names  as df2, I still get the same values in df1

Comment: @user3796292 I tried your sample dataframe it work on my end